# After a wrong input all subsequent inputs fail

Tags: c++, file

This is my code. I hope the user input and compare with the file if same with the file elements will break. If not the same, keep looping. But when I run this code, the first time I enter an invalid name, the second time I enter a valid name it will also keep looping(fail). When first time I enter a valid name it will stop looping (success). How can I solve this problem? thank you all first.

```
string line ;

ifstream DoctorFile ;
DoctorFile.open("DoctorName.txt") ;

bool foundDoctor = false ;

while(!foundDoctor){
    cout << "Doctor Name: " << endl ;
    getline(cin , p.docName) ;
    transform(p.docName.begin() , p.docName.end() , p.docName.begin() , ::toupper) ;

        while(getline(DoctorFile , line)){
            if(p.docName != line){
                foundDoctor = false ;
            }else{
                foundDoctor = true ;
                break ;
            }
        }
}
```

This is the doctor file:

```
DR ALEX KHOO
DR ABRAHAM LINCOLN
DR CHLOE ETHAN
DR MICHEAL JACKSON
DR BILL GATES
```

Comment: Use a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the file position on the begin after the second while. If you already read past the end, you have to reset the error flags with clear() as @MarekR added.

```
string line ;

ifstream DoctorFile ;
DoctorFile.open("DoctorName.txt") ;

bool foundDoctor = false ;

while(!foundDoctor){
    cout << "Doctor Name: " << endl ;
    getline(cin , p.docName) ;
    transform(p.docName.begin() , p.docName.end() , p.docName.begin() , ::toupper) ;

        while(!foundDoctor && getline(DoctorFile , line)){
            foundDoctor = (p.docName == line);
        }
    DoctorFile.clear();
    DoctorFile.seekg(0);
}
```